# How do I efficiently replace a function with a lookup?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

I am trying to increase the speed of code that operates on large datasets. I need to perform the function `out = sinc(x)`, where `x` is a *2048*-by-*37499* matrix of doubles. This is very expensive and is the bottleneck of my program (even when computed on the GPU).

I am looking for any solution which improves the speed of this operation.
I expect that this might be achieved by pre-computing a vector `LookUp = sinc(y)` where `y` is the vector `y = min(min(x)):dy:max(max(x))`, i.e. a vector spanning the whole range of expected `x` elements.

How can I efficiently generate an approximation of `sinc(x)` from this `LookUp` vector?

I need to avoid generating a three dimensional array, since this would consume more memory than I have available.

Here is a test for the interp1 solution:

```
a = -15;
b = 15;
rands = (b-a).*rand(1024,37499) + a;

sincx = -15:0.000005:15;
sincy = sinc(sincx);

tic
res1 = interp1(sincx,sincy,rands);
toc

tic
res2 = sinc(rands);
toc'

sincx = gpuArray(sincx);
sincy = gpuArray(sincy);
r = gpuArray(rands);

tic
r = interp1(sincx,sincy,r);
toc

r = gpuArray(rands);

tic
r = sinc(r);
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 0.426091 seconds.
>     Elapsed time is 0.472551 seconds.
>     Elapsed time is 0.004311 seconds.
>     Elapsed time is 0.130904 seconds.

Corresponding to CPU interp1, CPU sinc, GPU interp1, GPU sinc respectively

Comment: I thought this question could be solved using `interp1` but evaluating `interp1` is actually slower than `sinc`

Comment: Can you provide a sample input for us to play with?

Comment: Will there be zeros in your matrix `x`?

Comment: What about a truncated taylor approximation? Might be faster: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sinc+taylor+approximation

Comment: Here is a test for the interp1 solution:

`a = -15;
b = 15;
rands = (b-a).*rand(1024,37499) + a;

sincx = -15:0.2:15;
sincy = sinc(sincx);

tic
res1 = interp1(sincx,sincy,rands);
toc

tic
res2 = sinc(rands);
toc

sincx = gpuArray(sincx);
sincy = gpuArray(sincy);
r = gpuArray(rands);

tic
r = interp1(sincx,sincy,r);
toc

r = gpuArray(rands);

tic
r = sinc(r);
toc'

For me, this result in:
Elapsed time is 0.426091 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.472551 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.004311 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.130904 seconds.

Corresponding to CPU interp1, CPU sinc, GPU interp1, GPU sinc

Comment: @Dan depends how far OP values are from 0, as the Taylor approximation for this particular function is only valid for very small values. (Already for x=1 it's very far)

Comment: @B.Thomas : The interp1 code maximal approximation error goes up to 28% though..

Comment: @B.Thomas : if you don't have any zero in your matrix, can you time `r=sin(pi*x)./(pi*x)` on the GPU please? I'd be interested to see the result (I don't have access to parallel computing toolbox)

Comment: @BillBokeey I'm getting an average of 0.0373s with a range of 0.0333s for 10 iterations on the GPU.

On the CPU i get a mean of 0.3948s with a range of 0.2070s.

Comment: Wow, that's actually 4 times faster than sinc!

Comment: @B.Thomas I ran your example code, thanks for posting that.  The results agree with my previous tests of `interp1` being twice as slow.  I am curious because I have a similar operation that could benefit from a technique like this.  My hardware may limit me as my GPU only supports CUDA 3.0 so I'm limited to Matlab 2014a.

Comment: What precision do you need, and how many significantly different (in terms of precision) `x`-values do you have?  I would be strongly tempted to truncate, sort, and bin your inputs, then calculate some smaller set of `sinc` values, and fill the output matrix with said values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a faster way (if you have a NVIDIA GPU on your PC) , however this will return `NaN` for `x=0`, but if, for any reason, you can deal with having `NaN` or you know it will never be zero then:

if you define `r = gpuArray(rands);` and actually evaluate the `sinc` function by yourself in the GPU as:

```
tic
r=rdivide(sin(pi*r),pi*r);
toc
```

This generally is giving me about 3.2x the speed than the `interp1` version in the GPU, and its more accurate (tested using your code above, iterating 100 times with different random data, having both methods similar std).

This works because `sin` and elementwise division `rdivide` are also GPU implemented (while for some reason `sinc` isn't) . See: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-built-in-functions-on-a-gpu.html

Comment: Note that this only works when you have a CUDA-enabled graphics card, i.e. an Nvidia one.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I understood completely your problem.
But once you have `LookUp = sinc(y)` you can use the Matlab function `interp1`

```
out = interp1(y,LookUp,x)
```

where x can be a matrix of any size

Comment: Thank you - this is what I was looking for! It does result in significant speed-up (depending on how many sample points there are in the lookup matrix).

To improve this, I will optimise the location of the look-up table break points to minimise the number of entries required for a particular maximum error.

Comment: Be careful, though, that the bigger the speed up is the lower the quality of the approximation will be

Comment: @B.Thomas I am curious about your implementation.  I tested this and found it to be twice as slow as `sinc`.  For my test I used random numbers of the form `x = rand(2048,37499);`  This seemed to be independent of the number of points in `LookUp`.  I did run this from the workspace and not on the GPU.

Comment: @Matt

Please see my comment to the above answer. For me, if the number of samples in the lookup table is small (less than about 6000) interp1() is slightly faster on the CPU. Larger sample numbers favour the sinc() function. On the GPU, altering the sample number has little effect, but interp1() tends to be about 30x faster than sinc().

Answer (score 3):

I came to the conclusion, that your code can not be improved significantly. The fastest possible lookup table is based on simple indexing. For a performance test, lets just perform the test based on random data:

```
%test data:
x=rand(2048,37499);
%relevant code:
out = sinc(x);
```

Now the lookup based on integer indices:

```
a=min(x(:));
b=max(x(:));
n=1000;
x2=round((x-a)/(b-a)*(n-1)+1);
lookup=sinc(1:n);
out2=lookup(x2);
```

Regardless of the size of the lookup table or the input data, the last lines in both code blocks take roughly the same time. Having `sinc` evaluate roughly as fast as a indexing operation, I can only assume that it is already implemented using a lookup table.

Comment: What takes time in the sinc evaluation is a call to `find(x==0)`. If OP doesn't have zeros in his matrix, it can go up to 3x faster to reimplement

Comment: @BillBokeey: That's a good point, using `sin(pi*x)./(pi*x)` it is faster than indexing. I tried to do some detailed benchmarks but my matlab version continuously runs into out of memory exceptions for that data size.

Comment: What benchmarks did you want to do @Daniel ? I think my computer can handle this

Comment: @BillBokeey: I compared `out = sinc(x);`, `out2=lookup(x2);` and `out3 = sin(pi*x)./(pi*x);`. I am using a old 32bit version of matlab, if you have a recent version which has the function run these three lines through `timeit`

Comment: I'm not so sure how to use `timeit` (liike that : `timeit(@() sinc(x))` ?)

Comment: Not sure because I only have an old version without that function, but it looks right.

Comment: SINC :  0.84009s ----- SIN(pi*x)/(pi*x) : 0.645s ------- The other one : can't get timeit to work

Answer (score 2):

```
m = min(x(:));
y = m:dy:max(x(:));
LookUp = sinc(y);
```

now `sinc(n)` should equal

```
LookUp((n-m)/dy + 1)
```

assuming `n` is an integer multiple of `dy` and lies within the range `m` and `max(x(:))`. To get to the `LookUp` index (i.e. an integer between `1` and `numel(y)`, we first shift `n` but the minimum `m`, then scale it by `dy` and finally add `1` because MATLAB indexes from `1` instead of `0`.

I don't know what that wll do for you efficiency though but give it a try.

Also you can put this into an anonymous function to help readability:

```
sinc_lookup = @(n)(LookUp((n-m)/dy + 1))
```

and now you can just call

```
sinc_lookup(n)
```